# C# populating datagridview from red shift connection and SQL query exception

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a button that when pressed should populate a datagridview with the results of a SQL query from a red shift connection but when it is ran I am getting my exception and nothing is populated.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = "Server=" + Properties.Settings.Default.awsconstring 
                      + ";Port=" + Properties.Settings.Default.awsport 
                      + "; User Id=" + Properties.Settings.Default.awsusername 
                      + ";Password=" + Properties.Settings.Default.awspassword 
                      + ";Database=" + Properties.Settings.Default.awsdb 
                      + "";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM schema.Table";
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
    try
    {
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        testdgv.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection error.", "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: The exception i specify in the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not opening the connection. Try:

```
...
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
...
```